# Mongo query difference filter roles between findOne and updateOne

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In this case result was updated even my param `block` is not `false`.

```
dbo.collection("privatemessage").updateOne( 
    { memberA: {$in: members}, memberB: {$in: members}, block: false },
    { "$push" : { "history" : objMsg }, } , (err3, result) => {
```

But in this case result is null just like i need it:

```
  dbo.collection("privatemessage").findOne({ memberA: {$in: members}, memberB: {$in: members}, block: false }, 
    function(err, result) {
```

Comment: How can I reproduce? Could you add the minimal example with exact values and a document that you expect to not be updated (only essential fields please)?

Comment: I short with time at the moment but maybe i hardcoded  value with mongo compas to false but string "false" .... i have work flow now but i need to check it again